# How to prevent applications from uncovering the technologies used on the website

Tags: 7, hooks, security

Here is a super hard question, probably for the most experienced people:

**Can we prevent applications from uncovering the technologies we are using.**

We all know that making sure to keep the core and contributed modules up to date is one of the most important aspect of web development. But meanwhile hiding information about the used technologies will another layer of the security.

Looking in the https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ and Google I can see the last time people talked about this topic was 2013, I think this is the time to ask this question again with hope that someone now have a solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean stopping them being able to tell the site was built in Drupal?

Comment: @Clive Thanks for reply, to be honest not only drupal but everything used while building the drupal site for example if visit my site the Wappalyzer show all the information such us "Apache, Drupal 7, Modernizr, Plesk, Twitter bootstrap, jquery 1.7, php, Google Analytics, yepnope.js"

attached screenshot http://picpaste.com/Capture-5Q395vXe.PNG

Comment: We'd only deal with the Drupal part of that here (for obvious reasons), but I think the answer is going to be the same as it always is - the amount of effort it will take to do it might make you think twice. For example did you know you have to edit the source and re-compile nginx just to get rid of "nginx" from the error pages? Time is best spent on _securing_ software, not trying to hide where it comes from :)

Comment: The jquery/modernizr/bootstrap/all other JavaScript source versions can't be hidden by the way, that's not possible. If the browser can read them, so can a human, so can anything else

Comment: @Clive I am looking for some sort of Drupal site code encryption, for example JScrambler to encrypt javascript and html

Comment: Just so your search is a wee bit easier: it be wise to forget about the term "encrypt". Encryption isn't relevant to this process, which is _obfuscation_ (different thing). But obfuscation is arguably pointless, precisely because of sites like Wappalyzer. They can execute code in various contexts, looking for tell-tale instructions that the original library would send, and infer what's being used that way, even when the code is garbled into non-sensical ramblings. Honestly, it's not worth the trouble

Comment: BTW if you do end up deciding to obfuscate your JS, don't pay anyone for it - NodeJS + Gulp + UglifyJS is all you need for that

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the information much appreciated, really helpful. Your star !

Comment: No worries! And having said all that, someone's bound to come along with a link to a module that provides all of the functionality you're looking for and more ;)

Answer (score 1):

Making all the Drupalisms disappear is hard work and most definitely not worth your while, as stated above by Clive. In addition, you'd also have to edit/obfuscate many of your http headers.

At that point, if it were me visiting your site all the SSL and Trustee certs could not make up for trust lost and I'd leave. Plus, I might tell my nerd friends what a suspicious weird site you run and turn them off too.

My advice: Don't break what makes the web work, and secure your site. You can and should stop nginx and PHP from advertising their version numbers, and you should delete Drupal's .txt files.